# Do you need a zero initialization for structs in D?

Tags: d

The C way is to `memset()` the structure, because by default it is considered filled with garbage. In C++ you do `= {0}` to zero initialize.

```
addrinfo hints;
memset (&hints, 0, sizeof (struct addrinfo));
```

What is a D way for zero initialization?

Answer (score 5):

It automatically initializes based on its contents, which are usually zeros (but notably *not* for `char` or `float` family, which are set to nan values, unless you set them to `=0` in the struct definition, on the individual fields)..

So, usually, you don't need to explicitly initialize D structs, the compiler will do it automatically for you and if it isn't doing the right thing, you should set it on the struct definition itself. If you can't change the definition though and do specifically need zeros, you can still use the C `memset` function.

```
    foo f = void; // skip normal initialization
    import core.stdc.string;
    memset(&f, 0, f.sizeof); // set to 0 with memset
```